# How is $\text{PE} = qV$ derived using knowledge of $F = \frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

I recently started grade 11, and this concept confuses me, since if we place a charge $q$ on a potential $V$, I do not completely comprehend what values would need to be substituted which would give me the formula.
The closest I have gotten is $F = kq_1/r^2$ thus
$PE = kq_1/r$, $k = 9 \times 10^9N$

Now i do not understand what values needs to be placed in $q_1$, and what the potential $V$ attempts to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric potential at a point is actually defined as such:
$$ V={PE \over q} $$ Therefore: $$PE=qV $$  It is not derived from the equation of the force between two point charges. Since you are familiar with the equations for the relationships between point charges, however, you can conceptualize the above equation like this:

Usually I think of the relationship between potential energy and electric potential as analagous to the relationship between electric force on a point charge and electric field due to a point charge. The difference between these two concepts is, essentially, that in order to have a force you need two charges: a source charge and a test charge. In order to have a field we only need a source charge, so to obtain the equation of electric field due to a point charge, we take the force equation and divide out the test charge. The big idea is that an electric field can exist regardless of whether a test charge exists, whereas force is only meaningful if you have a test charge on which the force is applied.

Similarly, the difference between electric potential energy and electric potential is the presence of a test charge. Electric potential energy is only a meaningful quantity if there exists a test charge to contain this potential energy. However, an electric potential exists regardless of whether there is a test charge or not. Therefore, a point can exist with a certain electric potential, such that if I place a test charge at that point it will have a certain potential energy corresponding to the equation $PE=qV$.

It is important to note that usually the electric potential and also the electric potential energy are meaningless quantities when looked at only at a single point. It is the change in these quantities from one point to the next that is usually what we are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

$PE = qV$ is usually used in parallel plates.
$V = \frac{kQ}{r}$ is the electric potential at a point, r distance from the charge Q. So given the charge and the distance from a point, you use the second formula.

$V = \frac{kQ}{r}$ was derived from $PE = \frac{kqQ}{r}$ and $PE = qV$.

I hope you get the point I'm trying to make

Comment: Thank you, i was not aware that we could use potential energy as electric potential V. Was thinking in terms of mechanical potential haha.

Comment: I assume what you mean is that as we have already derived the PE as kq/r, we can simply call it electric potential. 
So if in the equation PE = qV i put V = kQ/r
I will have kQq/r which is the potential energy for any two particles, Also, one small, thing, have you replaced the variables q1 and q2 by q and Q? Because q could also mean quantization of a charged particle?

Comment: yes that's what I did, q and Q for q1 and q2 respectively